# What does valid method overriding mean?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, object-oriented, types-and-programming-languages

In *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce, from p257 to p258, about featherweight Java,

> The predicate `override(m, D, C→C0)` judges whether a method
> `m` with argument types `C` and a result type `C0` may be deﬁned in a subclass of `D`. In case of overriding, if a method with the same name is declared in the superclass then it must have the same type.

I am not sure   what the predicate `override(m, D, C→C0)` means.

Does the predicate apply only to the case of overriding? (The first sentence doesn't imply so.)

Isn't it always possible to define a method with any name and any type in any class?

- In case of non-overriding, that is true.
- In case of overriding, that is also true.

Could you   give examples where it is possible and where it isn't?

Figure 19-2: Featherweight Java (auxiliary deﬁnitions) says:

> Valid method overriding:
>
> If `mtype(m, D) = E→E0` implies `C = E` and `C0 = E0`, then
> `override(m, D, C→C0 )`

How can `mtype(m, D) = E→E0` imply `C = E` and `C0 = E0`?
`mtype(m, D) = E→E0` only means that class `D` has a method `m` whose type is `E→E0`.

Why is "`mtype(m, D) = E→E0` implies `C = E` and `C0 = E0`" a condition for `override(m, D, C→C0 )`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The important sentence in the first quote is

> In case of overriding, if a method with the same name is declared in the superclass then it must have the same type.

So if you have

```
class C1 { ... }
class C2 { ... }

class Cls {
    C1 foo(C2 x) { ... }
}
```

`override(foo, Cls, (C2)->C1)` holds but `override(foo, Cls, (C2)->C2)` doesn't; the subclass

```
class SubCls extends Cls {
    C2 foo(C2 x) { ... }
}
```

is illegal. In FJ, you can't have

```
class SubCls extends Cls {
    C2 foo() { ... }
}
```

either, unlike in Java.

> If `mtype(m, D) = E→E0` implies `C = E` and `C0 = E0`, then `override(m, D, C→C0 )`

This is implicitly quantified "for all `E` and `E0`". If `mtype(m, D)` is undefined, then `mtype(m, D) = E→E0` is always false, so it implies anything. If it's defined, then "`mtype(m, D) = E→E0` implies `C = E` and `C0 = E0`" is equivalent to `mtype(m, D) = C→C0`.

So it ends up being the same as

> > If `mtype(m, D) = C→C0` or `mtype(m, D)` is undefined, then `override(m, D, C→C0)`

(unless I went wrong somewhere)